# Can I sort the "see the active scheme" list in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am taught myself language c in Xcode

and I create a each target for every file(.c)

When I build a file, I have to select the same target with a file.

but the target list(see the active scheme) is not sorted

So It's hard to find a right target.

I hope someone help me to sort the list.

[list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RGIO.jpg) <- this image can help you to understand the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sorted if the Xcode project is created by Cmake. See the examples like on https://github.com/ttroy50/cmake-examples to see how to create a project. That'll also allow you to manage them properly, delete and rebuild projects, share them with other people, and use other generators like ninja.

For the time being, you can type the name when the list is expanded and the target will show up.

[image]

Comment: This project include many files so I can't create project again. Howerver, I will try on other project. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: I find cmake files more maintainable, readable, and version-controllable than Xcode proj files. but you do you (: